# SystemCallFilter apparently not taken into account

Tags: linux, systemd, system-calls

I am trying to harden some services on my servers.

For this purpose, I have been using systemctl service configuration. For a given service, I run for instance `strace` to determine the system calls used on normal operations to create a systemcalls whitelist. Here is my openvpn.service configuration :

```
[Unit]
Description=a given service I want to restrict systemcalls
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=man:openvpn(8) service

[Service]
Type=notify
LimitNPROC=10
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rw
KillMode=process
RestartSec=5s
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server/vpn.conf
ProtectHome=yes
User=openvpn
Group=openvpn
SystemCallFilter=
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_ADMIN
ProtectSystem=strict
PrivateTmp=yes
#PrivateDevices=yes
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_INET
NoNewPrivileges=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

By running it on command line with strace, I know that for instance at least `sendto` and `recvfrom` systemcalls are being used. However, when I empty the SystemCallFilter (`SystemCallFilter=`), the service still can be loaded and runs as usual.

So is this option really being taken into account (and maybe I just made a typo, for instance, this is not the right syntax to forbid everything) ? Or maybe this option only gets applied for the service which launches `openvpn` and not `openvpn` process itself ?

The fact is, I would like to use this feature, but I don't know any way to check it really does what it is supposed to do : allow only listed systemcalls.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By running it on command line with strace, I know that for instance at
>   least `sendto` and `recvfrom` systemcalls are being used. However, when I
>   empty the SystemCallFilter (`SystemCallFilter=`), the service still can
>   be loaded and runs as usual.

---

> ```
> CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN
> AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_ADMIN
> ```

---

## Answer

These two chunks of  your question(above) kind of answers why your OpenVPN service is having access to all needed syscalls.

First: `SystemCallFilter=` does not block all syscalls. [Manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html):

> Note that the `execve`, `exit`, `exit_group`, `getrlimit`,
>   `rt_sigreturn`, `sigreturn` system calls and the system calls for
>   querying time and sleeping are implicitly whitelisted and do not need
>   to be listed explicitly.

Second: If you take a look at [`socket(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) manpage, you will see that pretty much all socket related syscalls(including `sendto` and `recvfrom`) and network interface manipulation features can be acessed if `CAP_NET_ADMIN` is set to a process/file. [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) manpage:

> ```
>    CAP_NET_ADMIN
>           Perform various network-related operations:
>           * interface configuration;
>           * administration of IP firewall, masquerading, and accounting;
>           * modify routing tables;
>           * bind to any address for transparent proxying;
>           * set type-of-service (TOS)
>           * clear driver statistics;
>           * set promiscuous mode;
>           * enabling multicasting;
>           * use setsockopt(2) to set the following socket options:
>             SO_DEBUG, SO_MARK, SO_PRIORITY (for a priority outside the
>             range 0 to 6), SO_RCVBUFFORCE, and SO_SNDBUFFORCE.
> ```

Third: `NoNewPrivileges=` will be ignored by `SystemCallFilter=`, `SystemCallArchitectures=`, `RestrictAddressFamilies=`, `RestrictNamespaces=`, `PrivateDevices=`, `ProtectKernelTunables=`, `ProtectKernelModules=`, `MemoryDenyWriteExecute=`, `RestrictRealtime=`, or `LockPersonality=` options. Take a look at the manpage above.

If you take a look at the documentation, you will see that `systemd` is full of caveats so, my guess here is that even if you are not allowing those syscalls, they are part of `CAP_NET_ADMIN`.

You can use `systemd-analyze syscall-filter` to double-check your openvpn service.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Just a little question if I may: how ``systemd-analyze syscall-filter`` can be used to audit and check if specified settings are truly aplied to my openvpn service ?